# Unity FPS Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I created a rigidbody fps controller by youtube tutorial and everything works fine except diagonal movement as it x1,4 speed bugged. So i tried vector3.normalized and vector3.ClampMagnitude but seems this is not an option for my fps controller solution as speed becomes constant and unchangable.
Original code:

```
    x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 moveVec = orientation.right * x + orientation.forward * z + Vector3.up * rb.velocity.y;      
    rb.velocity = moveVec;
```

So i tried this

```
    x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") ;
    z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 moveVec = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(orientation.right * x + orientation.forward * z + 
    Vector3.up * rb.velocity.y, 1.0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime;      
    rb.velocity = moveVec;
```

And it worked but when i hit an object and some random Y transform accures i fly in the air as rb.velocity is also multiplyed on speed and deltaTime. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Separate your Input from the current velocity and apply the `speed` multiplier only to the input.

Note that you are dealing with a **velocity** which is in Unity Unit per second. => You do **not** want to multiply by `Time.deltaTime` here!

```
x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

Vector3 moveVec = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(orientation.right * x + orientation.forward * z, 1.0f) * speed;
moveVec += Vector3.up * rb.velocity.y;    
rb.velocity = moveVec;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that is exactly what i couldn`t figure out)